# Testing private members with a SelfTest() method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I have a bunch of classes that wrap DB queries. I want to be able to test-run each query, and verify the result, returned to private members of my class. The perhaps barbaric idea that sprung to mind was to give my query wrappers a `public SelfTest()` method, visible to XUnit with a `[Fact]` attribute. As such, my test method would have access to the internals of the class and could verify in detail the outcome of the DB request.

Are there unhappy consequences I should be aware of? I would be adding a public method to my DB wrapper classes, but the method would do no damage. I would be making my application directly 'consumable' by XUnit, rather than having my tests in a separate project as I'm used to, but this seems harmless, no?

Comment: Why not declare the query methods as internals and make them accessible from the test project via the InternalsVisibleTo-Attribute in the assembly.cs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: Good tip thanks. To tell the whole story, [my wrapper classes are generated](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eaf390af-afc1-4994-a442-ec95923dafcb). If I can safely include the SelfTest() method in my generated class, I won't have to manage another location for code generation and life will be much simpler. Provided there are no traps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the SelfTest() methods to your production code will have no direct impact on the functionality. But your notion that this is kind of 
'babaric' is caused by the violation of several principles we know as Clean Code.

Just to name a few points:

- First of all this will violate the Single Responsibilty Principle. Beside the functionality itsself the class has the responsibility to test itsself.
- More code and more complexity is added to the class. Who wants to read all the test code if someone is just interesting in understanding the functionality ?
- You add additional dependencies to your production code (XUnit in this case) and the assemblies will be part of your shipped product.

But what is an alternative approach ?

Just making all methods and properties public for the sake of testing is not suitable as well. But with the `InternalsVisibleTo` annotation in the assembly.cs you can give the test project assembly the right to access internal methods and properties of the assembly to test.

Example:

Add in the assembly.cs of MyAssembly the line

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("MyAssembly.UnitTests")]
```

Then in MyAssembly.UnitTests internal methods can be used.

Comment: I take those points. But InternalsVisibleTo obliges me to promote private members to internal, which I'd much rather not do.

Comment: [did it :-)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bbsimonbb.QueryFirst)